# How do I export LEGO Mindstorms programs on the Chromebook

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

There is now a [Chromebook app](https://education.lego.com/en-gb/secondary/explore/c/ev3-chromebooks) to program LEGO Mindstorms.  I have multiple kids collaborating on programs for FIRST LEGO League.  Can they share the program between their Chromebooks?  I don't see a way to import or export the programs in the app.

Comment: I saw that, but the FAQ also says "Q: Can I access and share my projects directly from Google Drive?
A: No. Projects are stored in a hidden location in Google Drive that is not readily accessible for users."  So without some serious hacking, the files cannot be found.

Comment: https://education.lego.com/en-us/middle-school/explore/c/ev3-chromebook-faq

Comment: Lego Mindstorms  ...  https://www.lego.com/en-gb/themes/mindstorms/about?age-gate=grown_up

Comment: Lego Mindstorms app  ...  https://www.lego.com/en-gb/themes/mindstorms/app?icmp=LP-SHQL-Standard-Mindstorms_About_QL_Mindstorms_App-TH-MD-V5TJGYTVTX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from 2017 was correct at the time. Since then, "LEGO MINDSTORMS Education EV3" software has been replaced by "EV3 Classroom" which does not have the ability to share anything and this will not be fixed. LEGO customer service has confirmed this for me via email:

> With MINDSTORMS EV3 being officially retired, EV3 Classroom will not be updated to have this feature for the Chromebook or Android version.
>
> For advanced users with *root access* to their Android devices: The project files can be found in #/data/data/com.lego.education.ev3classroom/files/projects
>
> Workaround: Screenshots
>
> ```
>    ○ Press CTRL+ALT+Capture key at the same time 
>    Take a screen shot of their code
>    ○ This can then be saved to an email folder or a google drive
> ```
>
> The students would still have to recreate the code each time but at least they would have that as a reference when doing so!

It's extremely unlikely that any school district would be willing to let students have root access, so it's now screenshots or switching to a real computer. The Windows version of EV3 Classroom does allow sharing.

Very disappointing, LEGO.

Answer (score 2):

One of my students figured it out.  I have highlighted the buttons in the picture below.  The symbol with the arrow pointing to the box is import.  The send symbol allows you to email or store the file on Google Drive.

[image]